# This is an inquiry to use npm pkg module

Tags: node.js, express, npm

I created an exe file using the pkg module.
The project is an express server, and an exe file was created using pkg.
But when I run it, it ends immediately.

Install with npm install pkg -g
created with pkg app.js

Immediately exit after executing the exe file

I don't know what the problem is.
Please help, thank you.

Comment: Can you provide logs from building and logs from running the app?

Comment: Do you express server serve something statically? Did you configure your `package.json`? If you serve anything statically you need to add key `assets`., e.g. `"assets": [ "assets/**/*", "images/**/*" ]`...

In my experience using `pkg` isn't straightforward and often requires going deeper in the docs to set it up: https://github.com/vercel/pkg

Comment: It is an api server made with simple nodejs express.
Searching for port 3000 doesn't work.